# AJAX: Image Upload with a text input field data

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

My target is simple: I want to write an ajax where the value of the input field "gallery_id" will be submitted together with the file on the input field "fileToUpload". My reason of doing this is to change the name of the file with this format: $gallery_id.$incrementresult. Don't mind the $incrementresult as I've written a code for that already

Here's my sample script that I've copied. For the Ajax

```
**Note that #upload is a button**
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
            var file_data = $('#fileToUpload').prop('files')[0];   
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data);                
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', 
                dataType: 'text', 
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
             });
        });
```

For the upload.php:

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
   echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/project_photos/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
   echo "SUCCESS!";
}
```

How should I implement the gallery_id on the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following:

```
 $("#upload").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);
        var galleryId  = 111; //Your value
        formData.set('gallery_id', galleryId); //add galleryId to formData
        axios.post('/upload.php', formData)
            .then(function (response) {
                //
            })
            .catch(function () {
                //
            })
    });
```

Comment: on the upload.php file, how will the code identify the gallery_id from the $_FILES? How should it receive? I tried this but it did not work: $gallery_id = $_POST['gallery_id']

Comment: var_dump($_POST);